# Mac OS 10.14+ NSTextField in Sheet will not programatically update after sheet is displayed

Tags: cocoa, macos-catalina, macos-mojave

I have an NSPanel that I display as a sheet using `nswindow:beginsheet:completionhandler:`.

Once it is displayed, I change an NSTextfield in the NSPanel with `setStringValue`.

This works in 10.12 and 10.13, but not in in 10.14+, where the NSTextField cannot change after the sheet is displayed.

Any idea why, or how to fix this in 10.14+? I can find nothing relevant in the 10.14 release notes.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// Declarations

NSWindow *thisWindow;
IBOutlet NSPanel *progressPanel;
IBOutlet NSTextField *progressText;


// Show the sheet

[thisWindow beginSheet:progressPanel completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
    }];

// Update the NSTextField

- (void) progressSetData: (NSString *) data
{
    [progressText setStringValue:data];
    progressText.needsDisplay = YES;
    [progressPanel display];
}
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: The problem lies elsewhere. Prove that you are calling `progressSetData`, please. Show enough code to make the problem _reproducible_ if you want help. (By the way, you should not be calling `display`. Nor should you have to say that the text field needs display. It knows what to do when you set its string value.)

Comment: I have no way to prove to YOU it is being called.  I have proved it to myself by setting a breakpoint.  Plus, the code works with or without the needsDisplay and display on 10.12 and 10.13.  I just added the needsDisplay and display as atempts (failed) to get this to work on 10.14+.

Comment: You are correct that the problem is elsewhere.  I replicated the above without anything else going on, and indeed the text field changes after display.  What is going on in my app is copying data using NSFileManager.  I am still investingatiing whether that is the issue.  progressSetData is called between copies.

Comment: Sure enough, running [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath: ... in betwen progressSetData calls results in no change the NSTextField.  So I thought the problem might be that the disk activity was on the main thread, but even if I used Grand Central dispatch tocopy with dispatch_async,, then wait for the copy to finish, the NSTextField does not change until all copying...anywhere...is done.